# facebook comments

Tags: facebook, api, url, comments

how can I get more different facebook comments on the same url?
For example if I click on a link, a set of facebook comments must appear, but if I click
on another link, a different set of comments must appear .I do not want to use an iframe
or refresh the page .
Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and look at their documentation about [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

```
$("#element").click(function(){
    $("#comments").load('comment_iframe1.html');
});
$("#element2").click(function(){
    $("#comments").load('comment_iframe2.html');
});
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have 'comment_iframe1.html' .Everything is in one page .

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the exact parsing it does, but couldn't you add hash tags or variables to the end of the file name?  such as comment_iframe1.html?page_id=1 or something similar?